# What does this Chinese character 天 mean on my visa?

Tags: visas, china, languages, chinese-language

In my Chinese visa, against "Days after entry", I find this character: 天

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E5%A4%A9) says it means day, sky, heavens, God, etc. What exactly does it mean in this context?

Edit: You can see it here:

[image: enter image description here!]

Comment: It means "days" (天 means sky. The only time you can see the blue sky is daytime, and that's where the meaning "days" originated.)

Comment: The translation to English is directly beneath the character in question--and even mentioned in the question. I don't understand why this question was asked. :/

Comment: @Flimzy Because some people feel uneasy if they just assume the meaning of the visa, and prefer to know it? I would.

Comment: @Flimzy 1) Because some of the other Chinese characters did not have an English counterpart. Eg. the place where the visa was issued. 2) Because when travelling to other countries especially where there is a language barrier you should be extra cautious not to break visa or any rules for that matter. An overstay in EU is not serious but could get you serious jail time in some countries.

Comment: Sometimes in English moons = months. Kinda like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"天" means "days". You might be confused by the "after entry" part and thought why "天" is translated into "days after entry". This is because of Chinese word order. In English, "after entry" is placed at the end of the sentence, after the number 090; while in Chinese, it ("入境后") is placed at the beginning.

Answer (score 25):

I think it means "days".

It's just a name of the field "days after entry" on chinese language.

"Duration of each stay 090 days"

Comment: To verify @MikkaRin is correct, simply enter 90天 into Google translate. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

It is preceded by (English and Chinese) text that says "Length of stay." And then the number 90.

So the whole message reads: Length of stay: 90 DAYs, with 天 meaning "days." That's typical for a visa.

Answer (score 0):

天 can also mean day(s) (as stated by Google Translate) and is the most appropriate translation here (given that the English says `days after entry`. Any decent dictionary, [such as Nciku here](http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/detail/%E5%A4%A9/41449), will give that as a definition with some explanation. However, 天 in the sense of "days" is never used alone as a word and generally comes with some sort of qualifier.

Answer (score -2):

In this context, 天 means day. But in the traditional Chinese culture, if you say 天 as a single word, it has the meaning as "God". For example, you can say 我的天 in China to express your surprise or strong emotions, just like "My God". Yes, 天 actually has the same position in Chinese culture as the God.